# How to not remove the Authorization Header on Jmeter Recording

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter removes the Authorization Header upon recording for security reasons, I understand that but not removing it is very convenient for performance testing

I know there are answers here but I can not see the files that I need to set, comment, config and so on.. Setup the Authorization Header but with broad explanation.. I need a very detailed explanation on how to do this..

I am using MAC OSX 10.11 El Capitan

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Authorization Manager supports several authentication types, to wit:

- [Basic HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- [NTLM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/)

For Basic authentication it is quite enough to provide the credentials (username and password combination).

The latter are a little bit more tricky, check out [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for detailed JMeter setup instructions for bypassing NTLM and Kerberos authentication challenges

Comment: Thanks you very much!